# How do I interpret the perfect tense in “Qu'as tu-fait”?

Tags: sens, passé-composé

In a recent test, I was asked the question

> Qu'as-tu fait la semaine dernière sur l'ordinateur?

which I would literally translate as

> What have you done (the) last week on the computer?

My confusion is with the nuance of this sentence: that is, does this mean

> Tell me *one* thing you did one week ago on the computer.

or

> List *all* of the things you have done *within* the last week on the computer.

?

Also, regardless of the answer, could you tell me what *would* be the equivalent expression for each of these?

Comment: Why, when the English sentence communicates neither nuance, would one assume that the French sentence communicates either?

Answer (score 3):

It is neither "**all the things**" nor "(just) **one thing**".

The question is not specific about the amount of information asked so should be understood to mean "what noteworthy thing(s) did you do last week on the computer?".

*La semaine dernière* **always** means "last calendar week", never the previous seven days just like *l'année dernière* means 2017 if we are in 2018, not the last 365 days<sup>1</sup>.

*La semaine dernière* doesn't mean "one week ago" although "one week ago" necessarily occurred *la semaine dernière*. *La semaine dernière* can mean anything between "any time belonging to the previous calendar week" and "during the whole previous week".

Note also that *semaine* is often only a period of five days, Monday to Friday, the whole week being the concatenation of *semaine* and *week-end*. Unlike in the US and many countries, Sunday is generally considered the last day of the week in France.

---

> Tell me **one thing** you did **one week ago** on the computer.

would translate to:

> *Dis-moi **une chose** que tu as faite sur l'ordinateur **il y a une semaine**.*

while:

> List **all of the things** you have done **within the last week** on the computer.

would be:

> *Dis-moi* (or *fait-moi la liste de*) ***tout** ce que tu as fait sur l'ordinateur (**durant** / **au cours de**) **la semaine dernière**.*

If you ask about the current ending week, not the previous one, you might ask:

> *Dis-moi tout ce que tu as fait sur l'ordinateur **cette semaine**.*

<sup>1</sup><sub>One exception is when referring to schools/universities where the year, noted for example *2018-2019*, starts in September and ends in June or early July</sub>

Answer (score 0):

"List all the things", definitely.

With an undertone of 'if anything' thrown in.  And of course it's not clear whether you're talking about the last 7 days, or the last calendar week, context would be everything there.

Also, it's not the perfect, it's the passé composé.  Just saying :-).

Comment: Whoops, I guess that shows my understanding of tense names. I thought that was the case, but I was a bit confused since a French person might say, for example, "La semaine dernière, je suis allée au cinéma." - in this case "la semaine dernière" seems to mean more like "exactly one week ago." But I suppose that's a different usage.

Comment: The passé composé is called perfect in French grammars for Anglophones.

Comment: Thanks dimitris. But the corresponding English grammar term is really 'present perfect' http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-do.html (there is a 'continuous' version as well, AND both corresponding future ones.  just to add to the fun).

Comment: It's common practice in French Grammars  written for Anglophones. Plus-que-parfait s'appelle past perfect or pluperfect. https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-perfect/

Comment: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/the-perfect-tense

Comment: And the imparfait se dit imperfect (tense) in contrast to the perfect one:-)!

Comment: I don't know if you are a French native speaker but there are several things of French grammar that they are not presented the same way in French grammar book for Anglophones. For instance Larousse, Bescherelle and the like talk about three groups of French verbs (regular -er, regular -ir and irregulars). The latter category talks usually about four groups (-er, -ir. -re like vendre, attendre, rompre and similar verbs, irregulars).

Comment: See here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29458/groupes-des-verbes and here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12566/why-are-there-three-groups-of-verbs-in-french

Comment: Another unknown to French natifs is the so-called mnemonic rule of MRS and Dr VANDERTRAMPP for the verbs conjugated with être in compound tenses. See here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/dr-and-mrs-vandertrampp/16805#16805 and here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/what-is-the-difference-between-the-verb-sortir-being-conjugated-with-%C3%AAtre-or-a/30373#30373 for instance.

Comment: We should all keep in mind here that grammar terms have evolved, on both sides of the Atlantic, for both languages.  So there's lots of room for confusion, depending on when the references were written, and the national origin of their authors.  I personally am glad for instance that the real 'perfect', the passe (soit-disant) simple has gone to the graveyard of nasty tenses in my lifetime :-).

Comment: @dimitris English indeed use "perfect" for the *passé composé* but if a tense should be named *parfait* in French, that would be the *passé simple* which comes straight from the Classical Latin *perfectum*.

Answer (score -2):

> Qu'as-tu fait la semaine dernière sur l'ordinateur?

In rendering this the past simple must be used.

- What did you do on the computer last week?

If you had used "this week" instead of "last week" then you would have had to use the present perfect as the action would not have been finished at the time of talking.

- What have you done this week on the computer?

As I understand

> "Tell me *one* thing you did one week ago on the computer.",

where "one" is stressed, the person who is speaking wants to know  one single thing from possibly many things that have been done and this context is not common. A translation would be as follows.

- Dites moi une seule des choses que vous avez faites sur l'ordinateur il y a une semaine.

This English sentence cannot be confused with the next, which context is found often enough; the time of the action in the past is punctual (…you did one week ago…) but it can be supposed that is understated a particular happening (for instance, one week ago took place a full day's testing of the ability to use the machine).

> "Tell me *of one single* thing you did one week ago on the computer." (*meaning "I  know well that you did nothing, not a single thing."*)

The translation would be this (the subjunctive is needed);

- Parlez moi de seulement une chose que vous **ayez faite** sur l'ordinateur il y a une semaine.

**B** The context of the last sentence is common; it shows no difficulty. Adverbs of emphasis have to be added in order to make up for the oral stress which does not exist in French.

> List *all* of the things you have done *within* the last week on the computer.

Énumérez précisément toutes les choses que vous avez faites sur l'ordinateur pendant exactement toute la semaine dernière.